# How can I find limit superior and limit inferior of this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

**The sequence given is:** $x_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} + \frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}$

I found the limits for the subsequence for n=2k and n=2k+1 as follows:

$\forall n,k \in \Bbb{N}$

when $n=2k \,, x_n = \frac{1}{n}+1 $, we get: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = 1$

when $n=2k-1 \, , x_n = \frac{-1}{n}+0$, we get: $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = 0$

I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: state the definitions of limit superior and limit inferior and then state what is preventing the continuation.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. From what you have you can conclude that
$$
-\frac1n\leq x_n\leq 1+\frac1n.
$$
Those inequalities imply that any sequential limit is in $[0,1]$. As you have sequences that go to $0$ and to $1$, you have shown that
$$
\liminf_nx_n=0,\qquad \limsup_nx_n=1. 
$$